# Python PID simulator controller output

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation, matplotlib

I have written a piece of [code (in Py3) that graphs out the controller value of PID controller](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=PID%20controller%20graphs&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=658&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjurp6wpYzSAhUMWrwKHaz-DGcQ_AUIBigB). This is so that by changing the various sub controllers (P/I/D) I can visualise how the graph changes. I've written the following code, but having difficulty in the PID algorithm, and obtaining a correct controller value. You can run the code as is, and it should output a graph. The code works correctly as intended.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3

import random
from decimal import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# SOURCE: http://blog.nikmartin.com/2012/11/process-control-for-dummies-like-me.html

y_data = []
x_data = []
error_value_data = []
current_value_data = []
controller_output_data = []
proportional_value_data = []
integral_value_data = []
derivative_value_data = []
setpoint_value_data = []
process_value_data = []

OUTGOING_FILES_DIRECTORY = "/some/dir/in/your/computer"

def create_offset(setpoint_value):
    offset_value = random.randint(-128, 128)
    offset_value_incrementation = float(offset_value / 100)
    return setpoint_value - offset_value_incrementation


def Pt_controller(process_error_value, Pgain_value):
    Pt = process_error_value * Pgain_value
    return Pt


def It_controller(It, process_error_value, Igain_value):
    It = It + process_error_value
    It = It * Igain_value
    return It


def Dt_controller(current_control_output_value, previous_control_output_value, derivative_gain_value):
    Dt = (current_control_output_value - previous_control_output_value) * derivative_gain_value
    # print(current_control_output_value, previous_control_output_value, Dt)
    return Dt

def process_error(setpoint_value, current_value):
    return setpoint_value - current_value

def pid_controller(proportional_value, integral_value, derivative_value):
    pid_output = derivative_value + (proportional_value + integral_value)
    return pid_output

def graph_line_data(x_value, error_value, proportional_value, integral_value, derivative_value, setpoint_value, process_value, PID_value):

    if max(x_value) > 500:
        width = max(x_value)/200
    else:
        width = 10
    height = 5
    plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=100)

    # Choose which data
    plt.plot(x_value, PID_value, '#FF4500')
    # plt.plot(x_value, error_value, 'r')
    # plt.plot(x_value, proportional_value, '#9F00A0')
    # plt.plot(x_value, integral_value, 'green')
    # plt.plot(x_value, derivative_value, '#00BBFF')
    plt.plot(x_value, setpoint_value, 'k--')
    # plt.plot(x_value, process_value, 'b')

    plt.xlabel('Iteration Count')
    plt.ylabel('Output')
    plt.title('PID Controller\n(P=0.82, I=0.155, D=0.45)')

    plt.legend(['PID Controller Output', 'Set point'], loc='upper right')
    # plt.legend(['PID Controller Output'], loc='upper right')

    # plt.legend(['PID Controller Output', 'Error Value', 'Integral Value'], loc='upper right')

    # plt.legend(['PID', 'Error Value', 'Proportional Value', 'Integral Value',
    #            'Derivative Value', 'Set point', 'Process Value'], loc='upper right')

    png_filename = "Steady_PID_Simulation"

    output_file_path = os.path.join(OUTGOING_FILES_DIRECTORY, png_filename)

    plt.savefig(output_file_path)

    print("Finished creating: " + png_filename + ".png")




def pid_simulator():
    # set point
    setpoint_value = 0

    # gain values          # P = 0.82 / I = 0.15 / D = 0.40
    proportional_gain_value = 0.82
    integral_gain_value = 0.155
    derivative_gain_value = 0.45

    # initialisation values
    derivative_value = 1
    controller_output_value = 0
    integral_value = 0
    x_value = 0
    number_of_iterations = 200

    while x_value < number_of_iterations:
        x_value += 1

        process_value = setpoint_value

        error_value = process_value - setpoint_value

        if x_value == number_of_iterations / 5:
            setpoint_value = 100
        if x_value == number_of_iterations / 2:
            setpoint_value = -300
        if x_value == 6 * (number_of_iterations / 10):
            setpoint_value = -200
        if x_value == 7 * (number_of_iterations / 10):
            setpoint_value = -250
        if x_value == (number_of_iterations - (number_of_iterations / 5)):
            setpoint_value = 0

        # PROPORTIONAL
        proportional_value = Pt_controller(process_value, proportional_gain_value)

        # INTEGRAL
        integral_value = It_controller(integral_value, process_value, integral_gain_value)

        # CONTROLLER OUTPUT
        previous_controller_output_value = controller_output_value
        controller_output_value = proportional_value + integral_value + derivative_value

        # DERIVATIVE
        derivative_value = Dt_controller(controller_output_value, previous_controller_output_value, derivative_gain_value)
        # derivative_value = 0.25 * derivative_value

        # print(integral_value)
        # print(number_of_iterations - x_value)
        x_data.append(x_value)
        controller_output_data.append(controller_output_value)
        error_value_data.append(error_value)
        integral_value_data.append(integral_value)
        setpoint_value_data.append(setpoint_value)
        process_value_data.append(process_value)
        derivative_value_data.append(derivative_value)
        proportional_value_data.append(proportional_value)

    graph_line_data(x_data, error_value_data, proportional_value_data, integral_value_data, derivative_value_data,
                    setpoint_value_data, process_value_data, controller_output_data)




def main():
    pid_simulator()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output yields:
[image: Steady PID output]

Comment: Don't seem to follow what's off topic Especially when it's on hold as "broken/not yet written" The code is clearly fully complete, but there is something going wrong, I just want someone from "StackExchange [to] Code Review" the code above.

Comment: If it is not working correctly as intended, then we consider it to be broken code and hence off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: Thanks for rewording the question in Rev 2. On Code Review, it is common practice to put apparently off-topic questions on hold as early as possible, to ensure that any broken code is corrected before anyone reviews it, since we don't allow the code to be changed once an answer has been posted.

Comment: @200_success My code was never "broken" to start with. I pointed this out 2 times. My question was put "on-hold" with an unjust reason. Furthermore, putting questions "on-hold" for unjust and arbitrary reasons can be "considered" as an abuse of power/privilege. The question wasn't "off-topic" either, as the name of this site suggests, it's for samaritans on "StackExchange [to] Code Review" individuals, not red-tape them.

Comment: @3kstc bear with **apparently off-topic questions** from [this comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155205/python-pid-simulator-controller-output#comment293705_155205). Nobody put your question off-topic without a reason. The way you asked your question ( (...) _but having difficulty in the PID algorithm, and **obtaining a correct** controller value_ (...) ) was ambiguous. I hope you get some good answers :)

Comment: Cool, your controller is going out of control. I would suggest a few things: 1)  your process value is a function of setpoint, it should be somehow a function from the controler_output_value that simulates 'the plant' 2) create a setpoint that varies with time 3) also create a plot of setpoint and proces_value 4) start with only a proportional controller 5) have fun

Answer (score 6):

*I want to start this review by explicitly saying that **I don't** have a deep knowledge when it comes to `matplotlib` but I'll give it a try anyway*

---

Have in mind that I just reviewed the code as is, keeping the same logic / functionality it has at the moment.

---

#### Unused imports

Don't import modules you're not using (`decimal`, `pandas`, `numpy`).

#### Imports grouping

From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) which is the official Python style guide:

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> 1. standard library imports
> 2. related third party imports
> 3. local application/library specific imports

**Refactored imports**

```
import os
import random

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

#### Spacing (a small aspect making a huge difference)

- you should have two new lines after each method

  ```
  def method_1()
      ...


  def method_2()
      ...
  ```
- use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. `Pt_controller()` should be `pt_controller()`
- the same rule as above can (and should) also be applied to variable names
- try to stick with a max length of maximum 120 characters

#### About the code

- try not to create variables which are used only once. Instead you can directly return the result.
- don't use global variables if it's not necessary (more, don't create useless variables unless you're using them: e.g `y_data` and `current_value_data` list are never used)
- don't abuse comments. Instead, there're the [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id32). More, debug comments are good, but make sure you take them out (*I did this*)
- you used `if __name__ == "__main__":` which is very good !
- you have some magic numbers which I'd move at the top of the program so that you can easily change them if necessary

---

#### Revised code:

```
import os
import random

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

PNG_FILENAME = "Steady_PID_Simulation1.png"
OUTGOING_FILES_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Main\\Projects\\Python\\untitled"
OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(OUTGOING_FILES_DIRECTORY, PNG_FILENAME)

DPI = 100
MAX_VALUE = 500
PLOT_COLOR = '#FF4500'

PROPORTIONAL_GAIN_VALUE = 0.82
INTEGRAL_GAIN_VALUE = 0.155
DERIVATIVE_GAIN_VALUE = 0.45


def create_offset(set_point_value):
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""
    offset_value = random.randint(-128, 128)
    offset_value_incrementation = float(offset_value / 100)

    return set_point_value - offset_value_incrementation


def pt_controller(process_error_value, p_gain_value):
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""
    return process_error_value * p_gain_value


def it_controller(it, process_error_value, i_gain_value):
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""
    it = it + process_error_value
    it = it * i_gain_value
    return it


def dt_controller(current_control_output_value, previous_control_output_value, derivative_gain_value):
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""
    return (current_control_output_value - previous_control_output_value) * derivative_gain_value


def process_error(set_point_value, current_value):
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""
    return set_point_value - current_value


def pid_controller(proportional_value, integral_value, derivative_value):
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""
    return derivative_value + (proportional_value + integral_value)


def get_width_and_height(x_value, weight=10, height=5):
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""
    return (max(x_value)/200, height) if max(x_value) > MAX_VALUE else (weight, height)


def graph_line_data(x_value, error_value, proportional_value, integral_value, derivative_value, setpoint_value,
                    process_value, PID_value):
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""

    width, height = get_width_and_height(x_value)

    plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=DPI)

    plt.plot(x_value, PID_value, PLOT_COLOR)
    plt.plot(x_value, setpoint_value, 'k--')

    plt.xlabel('Iteration Count')
    plt.ylabel('Output')
    plt.title('PID Controller\n(P={}, I={}, D={})'.format(PROPORTIONAL_GAIN_VALUE,
                                                          INTEGRAL_GAIN_VALUE,
                                                          DERIVATIVE_GAIN_VALUE))

    plt.legend(['PID Controller Output', 'Set point'], loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)

    print("Finished creating: {}".format(PNG_FILENAME))


def pid_simulator():
    """Docstring here (what does the function do)"""
    set_point_value, controller_output_value, integral_value, derivative_value, number_of_iterations = 0, 0, 0, 1, 200

    x_data, error_value_data, controller_output_data, proportional_value_data = [], [], [], []
    integral_value_data, derivative_value_data, setpoint_value_data, process_value_data = [], [], [], []

    for x_value, _ in enumerate(range(number_of_iterations)):
        process_value = set_point_value
        error_value = process_value - set_point_value

        if x_value == number_of_iterations / 5:
            set_point_value = 100
        if x_value == number_of_iterations / 2:
            set_point_value = -300
        if x_value == 6 * (number_of_iterations / 10):
            set_point_value = -200
        if x_value == 7 * (number_of_iterations / 10):
            set_point_value = -250
        if x_value == (number_of_iterations - (number_of_iterations / 5)):
            set_point_value = 0

        proportional_value = pt_controller(process_value, PROPORTIONAL_GAIN_VALUE)
        integral_value = it_controller(integral_value, process_value, INTEGRAL_GAIN_VALUE)

        previous_controller_output_value = controller_output_value
        controller_output_value = proportional_value + integral_value + derivative_value

        derivative_value = dt_controller(controller_output_value,
                                         previous_controller_output_value,
                                         DERIVATIVE_GAIN_VALUE)

        x_data.append(x_value)
        controller_output_data.append(controller_output_value)
        error_value_data.append(error_value)
        integral_value_data.append(integral_value)
        setpoint_value_data.append(set_point_value)
        process_value_data.append(process_value)
        derivative_value_data.append(derivative_value)
        proportional_value_data.append(proportional_value)

    graph_line_data(x_data, error_value_data, proportional_value_data, integral_value_data, derivative_value_data,
                    setpoint_value_data, process_value_data, controller_output_data)


def main():
    matplotlib.use('Agg', warn=False)

    pid_simulator()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm sure `pid_simulator()` can be improved even more but that's all the time that I have with me right now.